# Excel makro Looping through Sheets and changing the name of the 1st Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried multiple approaches, but can't get to make it work.
I need to loop through all the sheets and change the name of the 1st graph.
Here's the code (Type mismatch error):

```
Sub Change_Chart_Name()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(ws).Activate
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name = "test2"
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Maybe I could go different way into this? I dont really know, I am a begginer.

Comment: Replace the lines inside the loop with `ws.ChartObjects(1).Name = "test2"`.

Comment: And add a `If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then` before the suggestion of @BigBen

Comment: As @BigBen said - replace _both_ lines with his.  No need to activate ws when you can reference it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Sheets(ws).Activate
```

with

```
ws.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all of you! Its working now, although I needed to combine your advices a bit. Final Code looks like this:

```
Sub Change_Chart_Name()



Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name = "Chart 1"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2).Name = "Chart 2"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(3).Name = "Chart 3"
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: For a quicker macro (and less code) - replace all `ActiveSheet` with `ws`, and remove the line `ws.Activate`